# FileSystemWatcher under Mono: Heavy CPU load on Linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, mono, filesystemwatcher

I subscribe to changes inside a directory:

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(directory);
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess;
watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = includeSubdirectories;
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Most of the time this .NET 4.7 code works fine, but when it's running under mono on Debian, on some directories, I notice the following behavior:

- The CPU load increases to 250% (2.5 cores are fully loaded)
- The number of child threads increases, and they load the CPU

This continues endlessly until the app is totally stuck.

---

UPD: Additional research shows that heavy CPU load is caused by an endless flood of `WatcherChangeTypes.Changed` events on every subdirectory inside the watched directory (1-2 events in a row for every directory, when all dirs were reported as changed, it starts again).

---

UPD: [Minimal buggy example](https://github.com/Himura2la/mono-fswatcher-bug)

Comment: Given the answer below, you may choose to tweak `fs.inotify.max_user_watches` : See https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar#install-troubleshooting for details.

Comment: Nice suggestion, it looked promising until I test it. This doesn't help, at least if you run mono in Docker. I already have `fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 4194304` on my host system, and it reads as 4194304 by `sysctl -n fs.inotify.max_user_watches` inside the container, but the described problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

In Mono's Technical FAQ, you can find a [What are the issues with FileSystemWatcher?](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/technical/#what-are-the-issues-with-filesystemwatcher) section, which says that under certain conditions

> Mono falls back to polling the directories for changes, which far from optimal.

Experimentally, I found out that one of these conditions is:

## The total number of watched directories is more than 4096

There may be more conditions related to files count, but I did not met them.

---

So, you may face the described problem if the following conditions are met:

1. You run a .NET Framework 4.7 code under Mono 6.8 on Linux (or in Docker)
2. You use [System.IO.FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher) to recursively monitor a directory changes
3. Your [NotifyFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.notifyfilter) includes [NotifyFilters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.notifyfilters).LastAccess
4. The `find watched-directory -type d | wc -l` command returns more than 4096